# Unusual PermGen error only reproducible on CentOs

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to track down the cause of a PermGen error that does not behave like ones I have encountered before.

It occurs when hot deploying (yes I know) into a custom container (yes I know).

When running on a vm with

- CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
- "Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.76-b04, mixed mode)"

A PermGen error occurs reliably on 5 redeploys.

Running on my Ubuntu 14.04.1 machine with the same version of java I can reploy 100+ times without issue.

The test for the above is fully automated so all JVM flags, versions, code etc are identical.

The hot deployed code starts a JMS listener. I had initially assumed that the issue would be a ThreadLocal created behind the scenes by the jms code holding onto a class reference however

1) In the heap dump I do **not** see classloaders being retained - they seem to be being GC's as expected

2) Permgen is never exhausted on an identical jvm runnning on ubuntu (as discussed above)

It appears that the issue in some way relates to the underlying os.

Any ideas of what could cause this?

Comment: My 2 cents: time ago I had a strange problem caused by ulimit (see https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=414462#c14). After changing the "virtual memory" limit I could run the java process without problems.